# Fly a fixed wing single propeller airplane like a helicopter?

Tags: aircraft-performance, propeller, terminology, aerobatics, fixed-wing

Has anyone tried to "helicopter" an airplane?  And succeeded?  And posted this video on the internet where I can find it?

What I'm talking about with what I would call a "helicopter" maneuver in an airplane is to fly with the nose pointed nearly straight up while maintaining a constant altitude.  I don't expect the airplane to hover, and I expect that to be impossible since the torque of the engine would leave the airplane spinning like a top.  I expect the airplane to move horizontally quite slowly, slowly enough that the wings provide very little lift.  With the nose of the aircraft pointed nearly vertically it should be quite obvious that nearly all the lift is from the prop.  If there's a different name for this maneuver then I'd like to know what that is.

What makes me ask is that I saw a battery powered remote control airplane that flew in this manner.  It looked like a typical remote controlled airplane except its single propeller appeared rather oversized for the airplane, and it had small hooks on the end of stiff wires that extended forward from the wings to out beyond the propeller.  The "trick" it could do was that it could hang from these hooks vertically from a horizontal wire suspended in the air and launch itself into the air using this single propeller for thrust.  It could then fly about like a typical airplane would.  Then to get back to it's launching point it would point its nose into the air and fly about almost like a helicopter.  As I recall it could steer itself around using control surfaces no different from those on any airplane, at least nothing stuck out as unusual about the control surfaces and I don't recall anything in the commentary that would indicate the control surfaces deviated from the norm.  It could travel horizontally "forward" (belly first), "backward" (top first), perhaps even side to side (wingtip first) while maintaining a consistent altitude.  It could navigate quite well this way with its nose in the air "helicoptering" about, then once it found the wire it launched from with its hooks it could cut the engine and hang from the wire.

The commentary on the video I saw of this aircraft explained that the idea was to use this as an observation drone that was capable of flying like any airplane would to get high speed and long range, at least faster and farther than one could expect from a quad rotor drone, as well as achieve a near hover, able to follow a slow moving target or make tight circles about a stationary target.  The idea of launching from and returning to a horizontal wire was to allow the drone to recharge from overhead power lines.  The aircraft's ability to launch or recharge from overhead power lines didn't interest me as much as the idea of an aircraft that looked like a very typical single propeller airplane flying around like a helicopter.

I can imagine that this is an impossible maneuver by most aircraft by the virtue of the propeller providing all the lift.  This would require an airplane with a thrust to weight ratio greater than 1-to-1, and likely other features like a radiator capable of dissipating the engine heat with far less than optimal airflow.  This would require a powerful airplane like those built for racing and aerobatics.

The question isn't so much about if this is physically possible.  This radio controlled airplane proved the aerodynamics worked.  I've seen full sized piloted propeller airplanes go straight up before, and reaching considerable speeds and altitude in the process, so there's propeller aircraft with enough power to pull this off.  The question is more like, is there video of full sized airplane with a pilot inside flying about like a helicopter?

I can imagine an airplane flying like this down to a runway and landing in a space not much bigger than the plane itself.  It could come in real slow down to the runway and then shortly after the tail wheel touches the ground it "belly flops" on to the front wheels.  With all wheels on the ground the prop could be feathered and brakes applied to minimize forward movement.

Then for an encore the airplane could tilted up with some kind of hydraulic ramp to nearly vertical, and take off almost straight up into the air.  I wouldn't expect it to zoom off like some rocket, or even burst into the air like that little electric model airplane.  I would expect more like it slowly lifting itself from the ramp, likely twist about slowly from the prop torque to clear the ramp, then get a bit of forward motion to steady itself, and then gain some altitude and transition to level flight. Not only would this take a high performance aircraft but a high performance pilot.  I suspect it would be very dangerous to get close to the ground flying like this.  It would be dangerous to do high in the air, but at least with some altitude and a powerful enough engine recovery from a screwup is possible.

I recall experimental "tail sitter" aircraft with counter rotating propellers built specifically for vertical takeoff and landing.  That's not what I'm asking about.  I'm asking about a single engine, single prop, and largely "off the shelf" airplanes flown in a manner where all the lift is from the propeller and it's flying with no change in altitude.

Has anyone flown an airplane about like a helicopter?  Is there video evidence of this?  Is there a term for this kind of flying other than "helicoptering"?  If this is considered impossible, as opposed to merely suicidal, then I'd like to know why.

Comment: Some aerobatics planes can do this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_EMX7N9PjA

Comment: Yes, fast forward to about 3:10 to see the vertical hover in that video.

Comment: @GregHewgill  That proves there are single propeller airplanes with sufficient power to maintain a consistent altitude but it does not show the airplane maneuvering horizontally.  Perhaps the near comically large propeller I saw on the remote controlled airplane example is necessary to get enough air moving over the wings that the control surfaces can be used to move the airplane about.  With that biplane example the control surfaces would likely be far enough out on the wing to not catch any airflow from the propeller.

Comment: See this post https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65590/is-this-video-real/65593#65593  Wayne Handley and his PT-6 powered Raven is the only time I've seen it done with the airplane in complete control with the ability to maneuver at will.  He stopped doing the act in the late 90s, I believe because it was just too dangerous close to the ground.

Comment: @JohnK  An excellent answer.  I'm having trouble finding video of this feat.  It's not that I don't believe you, I'd just like to see how well it was done.  I'll consider this an answered question once I see some video.

Comment: I never could find a video of his act from those days, so you're out of luck I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking flying a single engine prop plane like a helicopter is not really possible since airplanes lack the [swashplate and cyclic style controls](https://science.howstuffworks.com/transport/flight/modern/helicopter8.htm) that make a helicopter practically maneuverable and at the low vertical airspeeds this maneuver would occur Im not sure how effective the control surfaces would be. With sufficient thrust you likely could get a prop plane to take off from a vertical position but I dont know of any light singles that have that kind of performance ([even fancy jets only governments can afford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrust-to-weight_ratio) hover just over the 1:1 ratio).

Comment: The question was specifically about single propeller aircraft, the Osprey and Pogo do not qualify.  I stated an understanding that this would not be something a general aviation airplane would be capable of doing but rather in the realm of a plane built for racing and/or aerobatics.  Given that this was demonstrated with remote control aircraft there is ample evidence that with the control surfaces close enough to the root of the wing they can get enough air movement from the propeller to be effective in maneuvering the airplane while in a hover or slow moving near hover.

Comment: I see you edited your answer to remove the mention of dual prop aircraft.  I was not asking about an airplane flying precisely like a helicopter with cyclic controls, just generally with the ability to move about slowly in a near hover.  I am fully aware that this is not in the realm of most aircraft, I stated as such in my question.